# How can I test IC LM2903 TSSOP8 with multimeter on the circuit board to see if it works?

Tags: integrated-circuit, multimeter, testing

I have IC LM2903 on broken circuit board, and I want to check it with multimeter. I'll be  very thankful on any advice or  answer.

[image: Basic]

[image: Symbol]

[image: Information]

[image: Information]

Images from [ST LM2903 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lm2903.pdf)

Comment: Leo - Hi, (a) As you're new here, please see the [tour] & [help] for the main site rules, as they differ from typical forums. (b) The [site rule](/help/referencing) requires an author who includes copied or adapted material, provides an actual *link* back to the source if the source is online (see the rule for referencing offline material like books etc.). || In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source of that copied material & added its link (you can [edit] if needed). Please note it's your responsibility to include source links for copied or adapted material in future :) TY

Answer (score 2):

That's very likely an useless idea. You have no control what other circuits place to the pins of your IC. You cannot see any pulses. Only a 100% static circuit could in theory be analyzed by measuring voltages and checking are they consistent with the known operation rules of the components. In a lucky case it's possible to force the inputs of the problem IC to static states (use wires, resistors or voltage sources) without burning anything, but that's safe only if you have the exact schematic and you are able to understand it.

You may measure with multimeter diode or resistance mode how tightly some input or output of the IC is connected to the +Vcc or GND in an unpowered circuit board, but you need the exact schematic and you must be able to understand it to be able to make any useful reasoning. We cannot help because we do not have that schematic and we do not have your board in our hands.

The only "this works if you are handy enough to do it" option is to detach the problem IC and either test it in a test circuit or to replace it. Before inserting the new one it's very useful to check what the IC gets as inputs and to simulate (with a resistor or signal generator) do its output state changes affect in the right way. Again: Exact schematic and the ability to understand it is a must.

Aren't we somehow limited and free of any creative imagination because we in every paragraph demand the exact schematic and the ability to understand it? No worry! You'll start to demand the same after you develop your skills to a competent electrician level.